# Upload image from client to server path using php

Tags: php, upload, path, client

I am uploading an image on the server machine successfully , but I need to upload from a client machine to the server.

I dont know what to put the path of the server , the server ip is 192.168.2.100

Here is the code am using to upload on the server machine

```
$p="C:xampp\htdocs\amena\images\items\\";

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$p.$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: I haven't done Windows for a long time but the path `C:xampp\htdocs\amena\images\items\\ ` looks wrong. Should it not be `C:\xampp\htdocs\amena\images\items\ `

Comment: You have to create the directory where you want your files to go to. eg. WWW/website/files/ .  Once you have that you can use that path. make sure you declare the authorization to edit and delete files from that directory.

Comment: You're missing a backslash after `C:`

Comment: didnt work i need to upload form the client pc to the server pc